# How to retrieve my own private playlist through YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve my own private playlists from YouTube, for display on my own personal website. So far, all the documentation appears to say that retrieving private user data (like private playlists) requires that your site's *users* go through an authentication process in order to provide *their own* authentication.

In my case, I don't wan't my *users* to authenticate, I want my *site* to authenticate to *my own* account every time it accesses the Youtube Data API, in order to retrieve *my own* private playlists.

Is that possible? I thought it might be doable if I could just save the authentication token for my own account, but apparently the token [changes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token)? And what's the most appropriate method by which I should obtain the initial authorization token for my own account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through the OAuth 2 for Installed Applications flow once, and generate and save a refresh token. Your server-side code can then use the refresh token to get a valid access token whenever it needs to make an API call on your behalf. This could be completely hidden from the visitors of your website if you code it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wasn't sure that it'd be that simple. I'll give that a shot and get back to you if I run into any problems.

Comment: yes but, what API call to make to get our own private playlists?

Comment: @Jeff Can you point me to the correct documentation as I cant find installed applications flow , here is the link to documentation page for service accounts https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Answer (score -2):

```
Credential credential = getCredentials();
    youTube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("Playlist Web App").build();         
    YouTube.Playlists.List  searchList = youTube.playlists().list("id,snippet,contentDetails");     
    searchList.setFields("etag,eventId,items(contentDetails,etag,id,kind,player,snippet,status),kind,nextPageToken,pageInfo,prevPageToken,tokenPagination");
searchList.setMine(true);
searchList.setMaxResults((long) 10);
PlaylistListResponse playListResponse = searchList.execute();
List<Playlist> playlists = playListResponse.getItems();

   if (playlists != null) {
        Iterator<Playlist> iteratorPlaylistResults = playlists.iterator();
                        if (!iteratorPlaylistResults.hasNext()) {
                            System.out.println(" There aren't any results for your query.");
                        }    
                        while (iteratorPlaylistResults.hasNext()) {    
                            Playlist playlist = iteratorPlaylistResults.next();


                                System.out.println(" Playlist Id : " + playlist.getId());
                                System.out.println(" Title: " + playlist.getSnippet().getTitle());

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This is not the answer, but common usage of YT Data API. He needs appropriate way to get private playlists, and the thing is in the credentials and managing tokens. How did you manage it? Please post answer.