# Displaying Own Data Using OAuth2 and Google APIs with No Login

Tags: coldfusion, google-api, youtube-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to build an application with ColdFusion.

I've been reading documentation and trying things out for days and for the life of my I can't seem to figure out how to display my own data to users from Google's APIs using OAuth2.

For example, I want to be able to display some of my stats to users with the Google Analytics API. How many unique hits, page views my site gets and from what countries. The data is private, however, so there isn't a way to do so. Or YouTube just changed their API so video tags can no longer be seen unless logged in. I want to be able to show my video tags so they can search for related things on my own site, but I can't pull them because I'm unsure of how to do this.

I know how to display and manipulate public data, but when it comes to private data, I'm at a complete loss. OAuth2 is kicking my butt!

Is there anybody that can please, please help me with OAuth2 so that I can allow my users to see my private Google data without there being any kind of log in process for them? Examples using ColdFusion would be so much appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: There's no support for Service Accounts in the YouTube APIs. (You can't delegate YouTube account access to a random Service Account, or associate a brand new YouTube account to a Service Account.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is more or less what I said at [How to retrieve my own private playlist through YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738262/how-to-retrieve-my-own-private-playlist-through-youtube-api)

You'd want to use the OAuth 2 for Installed Applications flow, and generate new access tokens via your refresh token when your old access token expires. I'm not familiar with any libraries for doing OAuth 2 in Cold Fusion, though.